# contacts_service.dart updates only to white data

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using contact_service.dart to update the phone contacts as follows:

**1. I make sure I have all the permits obtained.**

**2. I get an Iterable with the contact I want to edit.**

```
Iterable <Contact> johns = await ContactsService.getContacts (query: "john");
```

**3. I edit the data to change**

```
johns .first.givenName = expect "jhon2"
```

**4. I do the update**

```
await ContactsService.updateContact (jhons.first);
```

The problem is when I check the contact in my phone book.
The contact only has blank data, it seems like the program deletes all the contact information and I don't know why.

Can anybody help me?

Anyone who has worked with the "contact_service" plugin before and can give me a contact update example please?

Answer (score 2):

You can download https://github.com/lukasgit/flutter_contacts/tree/master/example 
and replace `contacts_list_page.dart` with the following full code 
When click update icon will call `_updateTest` to update `john`'s related data 
You can see working demo below 
code snippet

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Contacts Plugin Example',
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.create),
            onPressed: _openContactForm,
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.memory),
            onPressed: _updateTest,
          )
        ],

_updateTest() async {
    Iterable<Contact> johns = await ContactsService.getContacts(query: "john");
    if(johns.length > 0) {
      var firstConatct = johns.first;
      print(firstConatct.middleName);
      firstConatct.givenName = "jhon2";
      firstConatct.middleName = "hi";
      firstConatct.phones = [Item(label: "phone", value: "1234567")];
      await ContactsService.updateContact(firstConatct);
      refreshContacts();
    }
  }
```

working demo

[image]

phone

[image]

`contacts_list_page.dart` full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:contacts_service_example/main.dart';

import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class ContactListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ContactListPageState createState() => _ContactListPageState();
}

class _ContactListPageState extends State<ContactListPage> {
  List<Contact> _contacts;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    refreshContacts();
  }

  Future<void> refreshContacts() async {
    // Load without thumbnails initially.
    var contacts = (await ContactsService.getContacts(
            withThumbnails: false, iOSLocalizedLabels: iOSLocalizedLabels))
        .toList();
//      var contacts = (await ContactsService.getContactsForPhone("8554964652"))
//          .toList();
    setState(() {
      _contacts = contacts;
    });

    // Lazy load thumbnails after rendering initial contacts.
    for (final contact in contacts) {
      ContactsService.getAvatar(contact).then((avatar) {
        if (avatar == null) return; // Don't redraw if no change.
        setState(() => contact.avatar = avatar);
      });
    }
  }

  void updateContact() async {
    Contact ninja = _contacts
        .toList()
        .firstWhere((contact) => contact.familyName.startsWith("Ninja"));
    ninja.avatar = null;
    await ContactsService.updateContact(ninja);

    refreshContacts();
  }

  _openContactForm() async {
    try {
      var contact = await ContactsService.openContactForm(
          iOSLocalizedLabels: iOSLocalizedLabels);
      refreshContacts();
    } on FormOperationException catch (e) {
      switch (e.errorCode) {
        case FormOperationErrorCode.FORM_OPERATION_CANCELED:
        case FormOperationErrorCode.FORM_COULD_NOT_BE_OPEN:
        case FormOperationErrorCode.FORM_OPERATION_UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        default:
          print(e.errorCode);
      }
    }
  }

  _updateTest() async {
    Iterable<Contact> johns = await ContactsService.getContacts(query: "john");
    if (johns.length > 0) {
      var firstConatct = johns.first;
      print(firstConatct.middleName);
      firstConatct.givenName = "jhon2";
      firstConatct.middleName = "hi";
      firstConatct.phones = [Item(label: "phone", value: "1234567")];
      await ContactsService.updateContact(firstConatct);
      refreshContacts();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Contacts Plugin Example',
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.create),
            onPressed: _openContactForm,
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.memory),
            onPressed: _updateTest,
          )
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/add").then((_) {
            refreshContacts();
          });
        },
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: _contacts != null
            ? ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _contacts?.length ?? 0,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  Contact c = _contacts?.elementAt(index);
                  return ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) => ContactDetailsPage(
                                c,
                                onContactDeviceSave:
                                    contactOnDeviceHasBeenUpdated,
                              )));
                    },
                    leading: (c.avatar != null && c.avatar.length > 0)
                        ? CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: MemoryImage(c.avatar))
                        : CircleAvatar(child: Text(c.initials())),
                    title: Text(c.displayName ?? ""),
                  );
                },
              )
            : Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void contactOnDeviceHasBeenUpdated(Contact contact) {
    this.setState(() {
      var id = _contacts.indexWhere((c) => c.identifier == contact.identifier);
      _contacts[id] = contact;
    });
  }
}

class ContactDetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  ContactDetailsPage(this._contact, {this.onContactDeviceSave});

  final Contact _contact;
  final Function(Contact) onContactDeviceSave;

  _openExistingContactOnDevice(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      var contact = await ContactsService.openExistingContact(_contact,
          iOSLocalizedLabels: iOSLocalizedLabels);
      if (onContactDeviceSave != null) {
        onContactDeviceSave(contact);
      }
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    } on FormOperationException catch (e) {
      switch (e.errorCode) {
        case FormOperationErrorCode.FORM_OPERATION_CANCELED:
        case FormOperationErrorCode.FORM_COULD_NOT_BE_OPEN:
        case FormOperationErrorCode.FORM_OPERATION_UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        default:
          print(e.toString());
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_contact.displayName ?? ""),
        actions: <Widget>[
//          IconButton(
//            icon: Icon(Icons.share),
//            onPressed: () => shareVCFCard(context, contact: _contact),
//          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: () => ContactsService.deleteContact(_contact),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.update),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => UpdateContactsPage(
                  contact: _contact,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
              onPressed: () => _openExistingContactOnDevice(context)),
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Name"),
              trailing: Text(_contact.givenName ?? ""),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Middle name"),
              trailing: Text(_contact.middleName ?? ""),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Family name"),
              trailing: Text(_contact.familyName ?? ""),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Prefix"),
              trailing: Text(_contact.prefix ?? ""),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Suffix"),
              trailing: Text(_contact.suffix ?? ""),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Birthday"),
              trailing: Text(_contact.birthday != null
                  ? DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(_contact.birthday)
                  : ""),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Company"),
              trailing: Text(_contact.company ?? ""),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Job"),
              trailing: Text(_contact.jobTitle ?? ""),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Account Type"),
              trailing: Text((_contact.androidAccountType != null)
                  ? _contact.androidAccountType.toString()
                  : ""),
            ),
            AddressesTile(_contact.postalAddresses),
            ItemsTile("Phones", _contact.phones),
            ItemsTile("Emails", _contact.emails)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddressesTile extends StatelessWidget {
  AddressesTile(this._addresses);

  final Iterable<PostalAddress> _addresses;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(title: Text("Addresses")),
        Column(
          children: _addresses
              .map((a) => Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text("Street"),
                          trailing: Text(a.street ?? ""),
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text("Postcode"),
                          trailing: Text(a.postcode ?? ""),
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text("City"),
                          trailing: Text(a.city ?? ""),
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text("Region"),
                          trailing: Text(a.region ?? ""),
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: Text("Country"),
                          trailing: Text(a.country ?? ""),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ))
              .toList(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ItemsTile extends StatelessWidget {
  ItemsTile(this._title, this._items);

  final Iterable<Item> _items;
  final String _title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(title: Text(_title)),
        Column(
          children: _items
              .map(
                (i) => Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(i.label ?? ""),
                    trailing: Text(i.value ?? ""),
                  ),
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class AddContactPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _AddContactPageState();
}

class _AddContactPageState extends State<AddContactPage> {
  Contact contact = Contact();
  PostalAddress address = PostalAddress(label: "Home");
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Add a contact"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _formKey.currentState.save();
              contact.postalAddresses = [address];
              ContactsService.addContact(contact);
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.save, color: Colors.white),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'First name'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.givenName = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Middle name'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.middleName = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Last name'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.familyName = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Prefix'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.prefix = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Suffix'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.suffix = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Phone'),
                onSaved: (v) =>
                    contact.phones = [Item(label: "mobile", value: v)],
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'E-mail'),
                onSaved: (v) =>
                    contact.emails = [Item(label: "work", value: v)],
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Company'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.company = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Job'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.jobTitle = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Street'),
                onSaved: (v) => address.street = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'City'),
                onSaved: (v) => address.city = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Region'),
                onSaved: (v) => address.region = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Postal code'),
                onSaved: (v) => address.postcode = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Country'),
                onSaved: (v) => address.country = v,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UpdateContactsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  UpdateContactsPage({@required this.contact});

  final Contact contact;

  @override
  _UpdateContactsPageState createState() => _UpdateContactsPageState();
}

class _UpdateContactsPageState extends State<UpdateContactsPage> {
  Contact contact;
  PostalAddress address = PostalAddress(label: "Home");
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    contact = widget.contact;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Update Contact"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.save,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              _formKey.currentState.save();
              contact.postalAddresses = [address];
              await ContactsService.updateContact(contact);
              Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ContactListPage()));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: contact.givenName ?? "",
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'First name'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.givenName = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: contact.middleName ?? "",
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Middle name'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.middleName = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: contact.familyName ?? "",
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Last name'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.familyName = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: contact.prefix ?? "",
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Prefix'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.prefix = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: contact.suffix ?? "",
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Suffix'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.suffix = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Phone'),
                onSaved: (v) =>
                    contact.phones = [Item(label: "mobile", value: v)],
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'E-mail'),
                onSaved: (v) =>
                    contact.emails = [Item(label: "work", value: v)],
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: contact.company ?? "",
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Company'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.company = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: contact.jobTitle ?? "",
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Job'),
                onSaved: (v) => contact.jobTitle = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: address.street ?? "",
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Street'),
                onSaved: (v) => address.street = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: address.city ?? "",
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'City'),
                onSaved: (v) => address.city = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: address.region ?? "",
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Region'),
                onSaved: (v) => address.region = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: address.postcode ?? "",
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Postal code'),
                onSaved: (v) => address.postcode = v,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: address.country ?? "",
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Country'),
                onSaved: (v) => address.country = v,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all I want to thank you for your help.
I still have not managed to fix the problem.
I have copied the example code from your repository "https://github.com/lukasgit/flutter_contacts/tree/master/example", and installed it on my Android phone, everything works fine, but when I try to edit a contact telephone number. The same thing happens as with my code, the contact telephone number is changed to white.
I start to think that it is an error of the dependency "contact_service".  My Adroid phone is Moto G Play and my Android version is 6.0.1.

Comment: Editing givenName and middleName works fine, but editing phone number doesn't

Comment: work well with firstConatct.phones = [Item(label: "phone", value: "1234567")];

Comment: I'm doing it exactly the same way you say
firstConatct.phones = [Item(label: "phone", value: "1234567")];
But it does not works

Comment: Yes, I can see the updates, but it still doesn't work with my Android phone